# Proof verification of $\sum_{k=1}^n kq^{n-k}$ is unbounded for $n \in \mathbb N$ and $q\in\{\mathbb R\setminus0\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, summation, upper-lower-bounds

As opposed to the sum in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976535/how-to-prove-that-x-n-nqn-for-q-1-is-bounded) question I want to prove the following:

> Given $n\in \mathbb N$, $q\in \{\mathbb R \setminus0\}$ and:
>   $$
> x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n kq^{n-k}
> $$
>   Show that $x_n$ is an unbounded sequence.

**Proof:**

Expand $x_n$:

$$
x_n = q^{n-1} + 2q^{n-2} + 3q^{n-3} + \cdots+ (n-1)q^1 + nq^0
$$

Closed form for this sum may not be easily obtained in this form so try to transform it. Multiply $x_n$ by $(1-q^{-1})$:

$$
\begin{align}
(1-q^{-1})\cdot x_n = q^{n-1} + &\color{red}{2q^{n-2}} + \color{green}{3q^{n-3}} + \cdots + \color{blue}{(n-2)q^2} + \color{orange}{(n-1)q^1} + nq^0 - \\
- &\color{red}{q^{n-2}} - \color{green}{2q^{n-3}} -\dots- \color{blue}{(n-3)q^2} - \color{orange}{(n-2)q^{1}} -(n-1)q^0-nq^{-1}
\end{align}
$$

Which after some transformations results in:
$$
\begin{align}
(1-q^{-1})\cdot x_n &= q^{n-1} + q^{n-2} + \cdots + q^1 + 1 - nq^{-1} = \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}q^k + 1 - nq^{-1} =\\
&=\frac{q^n -q}{q-1} + 1 -nq^{-1} \tag1
\end{align}
$$

Now if we multiply $(1)$ by $(q-1)$:

$$
(1-q^{-1})(q-1)\cdot x_n = q^n - 1 -n +nq^{-1} \implies \\
\implies x_n = \frac{q(q^n - q) -nq+n}{(q-1)^2}
$$

Now consider $q^n$ and $nq$. Here $nq$ is obviously unbounded since $q$ is some given number such that $q \ne 0$. For $q^n$ consider the case when $0 < q < 1$. Let:

$$
q={ 1 \over 1+r } \\
r>0
$$
Then:

$$
q^n = {1\over (1+r)^n}
$$

By Bernoulli:

$$
(1+r)^n \ge 1+nr \iff {1\over (1+r)^n} \le{1\over 1+nr} \implies \\
\implies q^n \le{1\over 1+rn}
$$

If $q > 1$ then $q^n$ is unbounded. Therefore $x_n$ is an unbounded sequence.

**End of proof.**

Is it valid or have i missed something? Not sure whether I also need to prove for negative $q$, do I?

I forgot to mention that i'm only allowed to use precalculus methods. This problem is given even before the definition of limits.

Comment: Is $q$ always positive? According to the title, it can be negative too.

Comment: @Oldboy, you are right, it may be negative. That's why i've put a remark doubting whether i should consider that case as well.

Comment: Well, in that case, you should. Your proof looks valid but only for the half of possible values of $q$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint** write $x_n$ as
$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k)q^k$$